# MPAndroidchart - Candlestick chart is blank

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

As the title says, I am trying to include [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) in a project and cannot get the candles to show up.  Here is my code:

```
    List<CandleEntry> ceList = new ArrayList<>();
    ceList.add(new CandleEntry(0, 4.62f, 2.02f, 2.70f, 4.13f));
    ceList.add(new CandleEntry(1, 5.50f, 2.70f, 3.35f, 4.96f));
    ceList.add(new CandleEntry(2, 5.25f, 3.02f, 3.50f, 4.50f));
    ceList.add(new CandleEntry(3, 6f,    3.25f, 4.40f, 5.0f));
    ceList.add(new CandleEntry(4, 5.57f, 2f,    2.80f, 4.5f));
    CandleDataSet cds = new CandleDataSet(ceList, "Entries");
    cds.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    cds.setValueTextColor(Color.RED);
    CandleData cd = new CandleData(cds);
    candleStickChart.setData(cd);
    candleStickChart.invalidate();
```

But I get this:

[image]

Chart Xml

```
    <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.CandleStickChart
    android:id="@+id/CandleStickChart"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

The same code with a line chart seems to work fine.
Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Please include the XML for the part of your application you are consuming the chart. Perhaps you are using a background color for the chart (android:background="")? If you are, don't.

Comment: Edited to include chart Xml.  I do not set a background.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to replace your code with following.

```
List<CandleEntry> ceList = new ArrayList<>();
    ceList.add(new CandleEntry(0, 4.62f, 2.02f, 2.70f, 4.13f));
    ceList.add(new CandleEntry(1, 5.50f, 2.70f, 3.35f, 4.96f));
    ceList.add(new CandleEntry(2, 5.25f, 3.02f, 3.50f, 4.50f));
    ceList.add(new CandleEntry(3, 6f,    3.25f, 4.40f, 5.0f));
    ceList.add(new CandleEntry(4, 5.57f, 2f,    2.80f, 4.5f));


    CandleDataSet cds = new CandleDataSet(ceList, "Entries");
    cds.setColor(Color.rgb(80, 80, 80));
    cds.setShadowColor(Color.DKGRAY);
    cds.setShadowWidth(0.7f);
    cds.setDecreasingColor(Color.RED);
    cds.setDecreasingPaintStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    cds.setIncreasingColor(Color.rgb(122, 242, 84));
    cds.setIncreasingPaintStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    cds.setNeutralColor(Color.BLUE);
    cds.setValueTextColor(Color.RED);
    CandleData cd = new CandleData(cds);
    candleStickChart.setData(cd);
    candleStickChart.invalidate();
```

In this, you have to specify certain properties.

Comment: Success!  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I think you must use under 1000 value for your x-axis I don't know why but when I try this solution my chart work like a charm
if you want to add time for your x-axis you can divide your timestamp by 1000000000.0 and then in value formatter cross this value to your value.